# stopifnot() vs. assertError()

Tags: r, assertions

I wonder what the differences between `stopifnot()` and `assertError()` are:

`assertError()` is not found by default (You'll have to load the "tools" package first), but `stopifnot()` is.

More significantly, assertError() always throws an error message, even if I pass arguments like `TRUE` or `FALSE`, while `stopifnot()` does the obvious and expected thing.

Reading the manual page did not help. What is the correct use instead of `assertError(length(x) != 7)`? If `x` is undefined, the statement produces no error, but as soon as it is defined, it is producing errors, independent of the length of `x` (7 or not).

Comment: I don't think `assertError()` does what you think it might.  It is designed for parsing code to find an expected error rather than doing a calculation, and it only throws an actual error if it fails to find a parsing error

Comment: So these functions give an error when there is a parsing error or warning? It sound like a strange concept to me (I grew up with C's assert()).

Comment: No.  `assertError()` throws an error if there is not a parsing error. It is an assertion that there is an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is where they should be used.

`stopIfnot` aim at stopping an execution if some conditions are not met during the run where `assertError` aim at testing your code.

`assertError` expect it's parameter to raise an error, this is what happens when `x` is not defined, there's an error

```
> length(x) != 7
Error: object 'x' not found
```

When you pass this expression to `assertError`, it raise an error and assertError return the conditions met (the error in itself). This allow you to test the failure cases of your code.

So `assertError` is mostly used in tests cases in a Test Driven Development pattern (TDD), when your code/function is supposed to raise an error for some specific parameters and ensure when you update your function later you're not breaking it.

Example usage of `stopifnot` and `assertError`:

```
mydiv <- function(a,b) {
  stopifnot(b>0)
  a/b
}
```

And now lets make a test to ensure this will raise an error if we pass "b" as 0:

```
tryCatch(
  assertError(mydiv(3,0)),
  error = function(e) { print("Warning, mydiv accept to divide by 0") }
)
```

Running this code produce no output, desired behavior.

Now if we comment the stopifnot in mydiv like this:

```
mydiv <- function(a,b) {
  #stopifnot(abs(b)>0)
  a/b
}
```

And testing again the `tryCatch` block, we get this output:

```
[1] "Warning, mydiv accept to divide by 0"
```

This is a small example of testing a function really throw an error as expected.

The tryCatch block is just to showcase with a different message, I hope this give more light on the subject.

Comment: OK, I got it. Probably the naming and the terse manual was the point that confused me. Maybe `assert.IsError()` would be the better name. In a language like Eiffel one would add `require b /= 0` in `mydiv`, documenting and checking that `mydiv` won't work if `b == 0` (` not b /= 0`).